# $_POST to SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql, post

I am trying to create a Logging Table for future errors that will log all $_POST(s) that goes through a system I run.

I like to think I'm competent with PHP and I thought either:
`var_dump($_POST)` or `print_r($_POST)` into a `varchar(9000)` SQL table would work. But it does not. 
I have done a fare amount of research and this is the code I am actually trying:

```
    $post_error_logging = "INSERT INTO post (title, post, flname, stamp) VALUES('".$_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]."', '".var_dump($_POST)."', '".$_SESSION['username']."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-3 hours'))."')";
    mysql_db_query("database", $post_error_logging);
```

It's not working. Please any help would be hugely appreciated.

Some thing I have tried:

```
$this->db->insert_string($_POST)
```

Could not get this to function properly too....

Comment: have you ever heard about sql injection? :P

Comment: Do not use mysql_* function please as they're deprecated... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array so:
**iF the `KEY`s (input names) are important**
You can use [**`serialize()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to turn it into string then store it into the database.

```
$post_string = serialize($_POST);
```

And you can turn it into array again just by [**`unserialize()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

```
$post_array = unserialize($post_string);
```

**But iF the `KEY`s (input names) are not important**
You can use [**`implode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to turn it into string then store it into the database.

```
$post_string = implode(",", $_POST);
```

And you can turn it into array again just by [**`explode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$post_array = explode(",", $post_string);
```

- And use `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT` type in your mySQL instead of `varchar(9000)` for big strings.

Comment: All his variables will be strings due to coming from $_POST. To save on data size, it might be worth using `json_encode` instead. Nevertheless, you get an upvote as your answer is spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Quote:

```
Return Values

No value is returned.
```

See the Problem?

try serialize() and unserialze()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 0):

`print_r(xxx,true)` would allow you to concatenate the result as a string.

You mention varchar(9000)... I wouldn't assume that's sufficient to store the output.  You might want to consider using a text field in your database.

Also, ensure that you have a method to escape quotes so that doesn't break your query.

Comment: ...And does not allow recovery of that data. Also, `TEXT` uses an entire MySQL page per row regardless of how big the data is, whilst `VARCHAR` can be set to be significantly less than that.

Comment: I haven't used mysql in a while.  Why can't you retrieve data from a text field?  What would be the point of storing anything in a text field if that was the case?

Comment: You can't turn a `print_r()` output back into the object it came from. This is why the other answers are significantly more practical.

Comment: I did not gather from OP that his goal was to rehydrate the stored POSTS as PHP objects at a later time.  There were three basic reasons his code was going to fail.  However, you are right... Siamak's solution does represent a superior approach.